# Prove that Y/X and X are independent given Y is conditional on X=x, is $n(x,x^2)$ and that the marginal distribution of X is uniform(0,1)

Tags: statistics

Suppose the distribution of Y, conditional on X=x, is $n(x,x^2)$ and that the marginal distribution of X is uniform(0,1).

Prove that Y/X and X are independent.

This question is Casella Statistical Inference's exercise 4.30.

I proved that by using the bivariate transformation. Then I find the joint density can be factored. Then I show the independence.

The solution gives a quicker way.

> The quick proof is to note that the distribution of Y |X = x is n(1, 1), hence is independent
> of X. The bivariate transformation t = y/x, u = x will also show that the joint density
> factors.

I don't understand where n(1,1) come from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hint it tells is to perform the transformation using u=y/x and v=x, playing this out, you will see where the $\mathcal{N}(1,1)$ comes from: 
\begin{align}
        \text{Let } u=\frac{y}{x}, v = x,& \text{ such that } h_1(u,v)= v, h_2(u,v)=uv, \text{ then } |J| = \begin{vmatrix}
                                0 & v \\
                                1 & u 
                                \end{vmatrix} = v \\
        f(Y|X) &= \frac{f(X,Y)}{f(X)} = f(x,y), \ \ {x \in (0,1), y \in (-\infty,\infty)}\\
        f_{U,V}(u,v) &= f_{X,Y}\left( h_1(u,v), h_2(u,v) \right)|J| \\
        &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}v} \exp{\left\{ -\frac{1}{2v^2}(uv-v)^2 \right\}}|v| 
        = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \exp{\left\{ -\frac{1}{2}(u-1)^2 \right\}} = \mathcal{N}(1,1)
\end{align}
Therefore independence is obtained immediately.